# Images Display, Convert Base64 String to File Without Saving On Disk And showing it on Html/Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor

I have some problems with image display, my entity is the following

```
byte[] image {get;set;}
```

On my Database, it's supposed to be an jpg, pdf, png image that user uploads in a form. Persistance it's ok but the problem it's when i want to show it (in this case with a buttom), i can't find the way to do it.

I try The Following First(with a png file):

```
string txt = Convert.ToBase64String(image);
source = "data:Image/png;base64," + txt;
```

Then i call the source in html img tag and nothing, i think it was the data so i check it on this [Page](https://base64.guru/converter/decode/image) and it shows me the following:

> “text/plain”, but the decoder displays it as “image/plain”.

So I need to Convert Base64 To File and then i can make base64 to image with the first result.

I Tried Working with **MemoryStream**  ....... **FromStream** and always throw **Parameters Invalid** or **Timeout Exception**.

And to convert Base64 to File all solutions that i saw being like this one:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, Convert.FromBase64String(base64imageString));
```

But I don't have access to save the images on the Server so the only way to solve it i think it's not saving the images and try to convert those to a file in memory to show then.

Any idea on How to Solve This? Could Be a Misunderstood of Concepts? Thanks for your time

Comment: There is **never** a _legitimate_ reason to use `data:` URIs to move images around. Jus' sayin

Comment: And is it possible to get a file without saving it K J?

Comment: @LeandroToloza Yes, using the `Blob` API.

Comment: Have you found any solution?